# How to completely uninstall anaconda and jupyter? Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

My jupyter notebooks are no longer capable of saving files, so I need to completely uninstall all python, jupyter, and anaconda files so that it's like I never had them, but I can't figure out how. Uninstalling anaconda in control panel does not uninstall jupyter. Uninstalling it from anaconda navigator also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely uninstall jupyter:

```
pip install pip-autoremove
pip-autoremove jupyter -y
pip-autoremove jupyter-core -y
```

After that run

```
pip freeze | grep jupyter
```

and remove any packages with pip uninstall {package-name}.
If pip doesn't work try pip3.

Completely uninstall anaconda:

```
conda install anaconda-clean
anaconda-clean --yes
```

Then uninstall via control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was uninstalling successfully, but the problem was not Anaconda. The Windows Defender "Controlled Folder" protection was on.